# Why does my power supply circuit not function correctly when connected to a load circuit?

Tags: sensor, ldr, lamp, transformerless

My transformerless power supply on the left side of the voltmeter outputs 24V/12V until I connect it to my load circuit on the right. The voltage coming out becomes and stays at 1.5 V at most and I cannot figure out why.

Please help thank you. [image: circuit]

Comment: How much is the load current?

Comment: @EdHalfsunk, hello sir, thank you for replying. I tried replacing both resistor values to 500k and the output V in the voltmeter is still around 1V. may i ask why is C9 not of help?  in the original circuit R16 was supposed to be 100ohm 2watts but it exploded in my simulation so i replaced it..

Comment: @Justme, hello sir, thank you for the reply. current is close to zero, around 2 uA

Comment: This looks an attempt to make a DC supply which is not isolated with a transformer from the mains AC. If you are really going to build it you sail in dangerous waters. The existence of the question hints it quite clearly. Device like this can work only with a certain load. The lower series resistor should be there only to limit the startup current peak when the device is connected, 100 ohm may be well OK. But the 22uF capacitor looks far too big. The  1 megaohm should be there to bleed the dangerous capacitor voltage when the device unconnected. My suggestion: STOP as long as no-one has died.

Comment: What's LA3? A lamp?

Comment: You can draw 50-100 mA from this kind of supply with 2.2 uF. Be sure to use an X rated capacitor and a zener diode, that can dissipate 3W.